# Minecraft Bedrock Air World?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

There are many Minecraft maps I want to make without the struggle of removing a whole lot of blocks. Is there any `.mcworld` file that is already cleared out (only air)?

Comment: It's definitely possible in Java Edition with a superflat world.

Answer (score 1):

[This Wiki page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Superflat#Customization) has some information about customizing super-flat worlds on Bedrock edition. It appears there's no GUI to do it like in Java Edition Minecraft:

> Bedrock Edition has no interface for customizing flat worlds; it always uses the default configuration (one layer of bedrock, two layers of dirt, and a layer of grass blocks) even when the Seed Picker is used. However, custom flat worlds are supported internally, and can be used by modifying `FlatWorldLayers` in the world's `level.dat` file using an external editor.

The editor used to edit `level.dat` appears to be [Universal Minecraft Editor](https://www.universalminecrafteditor.com/), thanks MrParrot

Comment: NBTExplorer is for Java Edition, Universal Minecraft Editor (https://www.universalminecrafteditor.com/) is a similar tool for Bedrock Edition.

Comment: Okay thanks, will edit